# Alert Dialog Box font color in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing an app using AndEngine and I am using my own custom theme to use white background theme. My styles.xml file looks like this:

```
<resources>

<color name="white_opaque">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="pitch_black">#000000</color>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
  <item name="android:background">@color/white_opaque</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Everything is working fine except in the dialog box the font color is white and it looks like this:

[image: alert dialog box]

How can I change the font color to black for the text?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about an AndEngine bug best raised with its developers. (If [the approach recommended in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textColor) fails [as stated](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83243/alert-dialog-box-font-color-in-andengine#comment149372_83257), that's all we can conclude.)

Comment: So this is the bug and there is not any solution.

Comment: Is that a question? (Did I make a mistake in my logic?)

Comment: I was asking whether there is solution or not.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not an AndEngine developer.

Comment: Alright OK! It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

So far you only specified the background colors in your style. You also need to define the foreground / font colors for your style:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/pitch_black</item>
```

Reference: [android:textColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textColor)

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: @SudeepAcharya Does it work if you directly set the color code as a hex value e. g. "#ffaa00"?

Comment: Nope, it does not work by changing android:textColor.